# Ansible: Calling tags from role but they are not getting executed

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have some tasks as shown below

```
- name: Add the server's domain to the hosts file
  lineinfile:
   dest: /etc/hosts
   #regexp='.*{{ item }}$'
   line: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }} {{ LOCAL_FQDN_NAME }} {{ LOCAL_HOSTNAME }}"
   state:  present
  when: hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address is defined
  with_items: "{{ groups['cache'] }}"
  tags: [ 'never', 'hostname' ]

- name: Set the timezone for the server to be UTC
  file:
    path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC
    dest: /etc/localtime
    state: link

- name: Copy the NGINX repository definition
  copy: src=nginx.repo dest=/etc/yum.repos.d/
  tags: [ 'never', 'setuprepo' ]
```

and I call them from my playbook as

```
- hosts: cache
  vars:
   LOCAL_HOSTNAME: 'web02'
  roles:
  - { role: basic-setup, tags: [ 'hostname', 'setuprepo', 'firewall' ]}
```

But despite calling the tags explicitly, the appropriate tasks like “***Add the server's domain to the hosts file***” is not getting executed whereas “***Set the timezone for the server to be UTC***” is getting executed.

edit:
My command line is a simple

```
ansible-playbook server.yml
```

Here’s how the command was executed 
[image]

As you can see when I execute the command I don’t see any tasks for the tags I called from

- { role: nginx, tags: [ 'hostname', 'setuprepo', 'firewall' ]}

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "*despite calling the tags explicitly*" -- how is anyone to know what command you execute and what is your intention? In the code above, both tasks you mentioned have the same set of four tags defined. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50976278/2947502).

Comment: @techraf  Sorry if I was not clear. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

But you haven't specified any tags to use!

You gave your command as:

```
ansible-playbook server.yml
```

You have not specified any tags to use.

So, anything with tags of `never` doesn't get called, such as your two plays above.

[To use tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html), you specify the tags you want to use on the `ansible-playbook` command line when you give the command. For example:

```
ansible-playbook server.yml --tags "firewall,hostname"
```

You can also specify to skip tags:

```
ansible-playbook server.yml --skip-tags "setuprepo"
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for this. My fear here is, in the event that someone runs the command vanilla, they’ll end up running all the tasks or nothing. Can I specify what you have stated in the command line to inside the playbook?

Comment: Further research and this is exactly what i am looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674649/ansible-in-a-playbook-filter-a-role-by-tags-without-passing-at-the-command-l?rq=1

Comment: @QuintinPar I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it sounds like tags might not be exactly what you want. Or at least, you might not want tags on everything.